# layout goes wrong on safari and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, cross-browser

Can someone look at this site for me?I have a serious problem with the navbar. It can correctly display on Firefox and Chrome, but fail on IE and safari(iPhone).

hklti.hk/

If you look at the above page in IE and safari it will display all wrong.
Can anyone tell me which parts goes wrong?

Comment: You can attract more help from people if you provide at least a screenshot or a code snippet of your problem. It might be hard for an outsider to identify the exact problem you are talking about by just looking at the page.

Comment: sorry but I cannot provide a code snippet as It's a Joomla website, several modules are loaded on the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this; Hope it will work;

```
body ul, body ol{
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: perfect!!! It's work perfectly!! Can you explain to me why the layout of IE is fixed after adding this code? Thanks!!!

Comment: Most of the time, preferred browser is Chrome, but some html outputs are differ from Chrome than IE.